# BGE: KX_GameObject Attribute description unclear

Tags: python, game-engine

Here in this documentation: http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_75_3/bge.types.KX_GameObject.html
it says for the attribute *orientation*:
"[...]On write: local orientation, on read: world orientation."

What does that mean exactly?

Also it says that the attribute is deprecated since version use localOrientation and worldOrientation. Which ones do I use now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is deprecated since ages, but nobody dares to remove it from the API. Simply do not use it (and do not use position).

The **world reference** describes changes along the scene's coordinate system (scene space).

[image]

The **local reference** describes changes along the object's origin (object space).

[image]

Comment: I actually wondered if you could change it from read to write, or how it is meant.

Comment: Providing different value on read then on write is fine if you have an auto-adjustment. E.g. to ensure you always have valid values (limit check). - In the above situation it is simply bad style - do not use it.